# Trying to understand how to see all my owned NFTs using OpenSea API

Tags: opensea

I own 7 NFTs as seen on OpenSea [here](https://opensea.io/0x7971e1ce39a78e89137a69752a25fc85aa65971a). I am trying to use the OpenSea APIs to query these assets but I am unable to get their API to return the same data. This curl command only returns two of the seven:

curl --request GET --url 'https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?owner=0x7971e1ce39a78e89137a69752a25fc85aa65971a'

The other 5 are from a collection called buildspace-v2. Also tried this command which did not return the expected data:

curl --request GET --url 'https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collections?offset=0&limit=300&asset_owner=0x7971e1ce39a78e89137a69752a25fc85aa65971a'

At a loss with OpenSea API. Any one have a better understanding or is this not possible?

Thanks